# Extend BadResult to give different StatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

From an asp.net core Controller I can return `BadResult(ModelState)` and this gives a `statusCode` of 400. Is it possible for me to extend this, or leverage its code so that I can code `MyBadResult(ErrorArray)` in which a different `statusCode` is returned?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, it's just a helper method of ControllerBase class and you can add any method you like in your controller or derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `StatusCode` action result with object

```
//returns a response with specified status code along with an object
public IActionResult StatusCodeWithObject()
{
    return StatusCode(404, ErrorArray); //<-- or some other status code
}
```